# how to generate start date using new 7 full dates with month,year using jquery?

Tags: jquery, date

I have one start date and i am going next 7 days dates generate but month is not generate correct. i have start date is "**1509698284551**" in date format 03-11-2017 like this but i am go for the generate i am return 04-10-2017 so why this type date is generate i have no idea where is my mistake i don't know. any one know how can fix it.

This is my code =>

```
var today = new Date();
var daysSorted = [];
var FDates = [];
var goBackDays = 7;

 var StartDate = 1509698284551;// 03-11-2017 date 
for (var i = 1; i <= goBackDays; i++) {
var newDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date(StartDate).getDate() + i));
daysSorted.push(newDate.getTime());
}


daysSorted.sort(function (a, b) {
return a - b;
})

daysSorted.filter(function (obj) {
var d = new Date(obj);
FDates.push(("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + d.getFullYear())
})

console.log("DateArray => " + FDates);
```

my current o/p =>

```
"04-10-2017"
"05-10-2017"
"06-10-2017"
"07-10-2017"
"08-10-2017"
"09-10-2017"
"10-10-2017"
```

my expected o/p =>

```
  "04-11-2017"
  "05-11-2017"
  "06-11-2017"
  "07-11-2017"
  "08-11-2017"
  "09-11-2017"
  "10-11-2017"
```

Comment: I suggest you to use momentjs for your requirement. Its provide simple function to add days in the `moment(your_date, "DD-MM-YYYY").add(5, 'days');`

Comment: where can you please give me idea how can i used with my post?

Comment: Visit here https://momentjs.com/

Comment: using this my code it's not possible? with out moment js

Comment: Possible but the moment.js libraray provides an easy way to interact with date time

Comment: if you possible then please help me with my code actually i have used this code in my project and many time i am used so that time i want need whole space to change code if possible then i want change in my code

Comment: @hungrykoala how can it's possible i can check in Epoch Converter i am getting Friday, November 3, 2017 8:38:04.551 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var StartDate = 1509698284551;// 03-11-2017 date

var temp_data = new Date(StartDate);
temp_data=temp_data.setHours(temp_data.getHours()+3-temp_data.getHours()); // + 3 hours add in my locale(if need correct) and - current hours
temp_data = new Date(temp_data);

var FDates = [];
var goNextDays = 7;

for (var i = 1; i <= goNextDays; i++) {
    var newDate = new Date(temp_data);
    newDate = newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);
    newDate = new Date(newDate);

    var date_str=newDate.toISOString();
    var date_str_arr=date_str.split('T');
    var date_str_date=date_str_arr[0];
    var date_str_date_arr=date_str_date.split('-');
    var date_out=date_str_date_arr[2]+'-'+date_str_date_arr[1]+'-'+date_str_date_arr[0];
    FDates.push(date_out);
}


console.log(FDates);
```